# CLion erroring on compiling - call stack problem

Tags: c, clion

I'm trying to compile a hello world file in clion but I keep getting this error

```
"C:\Program Files\JetBrains\CLion 2018.3.1\bin\cmake\win\bin\cmake.exe" -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug -G "CodeBlocks - MinGW Makefiles" C:\Users\NAME\CLionProjects\HelloWorld 
CMake Error at C:/Program Files/JetBrains/CLion 2018.3.1/bin/cmake/win/share/cmake-3.13/Modules/CMakeDetermineCompilerId.cmake:523 (file): 
    file STRINGS file
    "C:/Users/NAME/CLionProjects/HelloWorld/cmake-build-debug/CMakeFiles/3.13.1/CompilerIdC/a.exe"
    cannot be read.
```

How do I get rid of it?

[Image of tooltip section](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UMVk8.png)

EDIT:

I keep getting the following compile error:

====================[ Build | HelloWorld | Debug ]==============================
"C:\Program Files\JetBrains\CLion 2018.3.1\bin\cmake\win\bin\cmake.exe" --build C:\Users\ssez\CLionProjects\HelloWorld\cmake-build-debug --target HelloWorld -- -j 4
[ 33%] Linking C executable HelloWorld.exe
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/6.3.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot open output file HelloWorld.exe: Permission denied
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
mingw32-make.exe[3]: *** [HelloWorld.exe] Error 1
CMakeFiles\HelloWorld.dir\build.make:99: recipe for target 'HelloWorld.exe' failed
mingw32-make.exe[2]:**  [CMakeFiles/HelloWorld.dir/all] Error 2
CMakeFiles\Makefile2:71: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/HelloWorld.dir/all' failed
mingw32-make.exe[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UMVk8.png):  **[CMakeFiles/HelloWorld.dir/rule] Error 2
CMakeFiles\Makefile2:83: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/HelloWorld.dir/rule' failed
mingw32-make.exe: *** [HelloWorld] Error 2
Makefile:117: recipe for target 'HelloWorld' failed

Comment: "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\CLion 2018.3.1\bin\cmake\win\bin\cmake.exe" -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug -G "CodeBlocks - MinGW Makefiles" C:\Users\NAME\CLionProjects\HelloWorld
CMake Error at C:/Program Files/JetBrains/CLion 2018.3.1/bin/cmake/win/share/cmake-3.13/Modules/CMakeDetermineCompilerId.cmake:523 (file):
  file STRINGS file
  "C:/Users/NAME/CLionProjects/HelloWorld/cmake-build-debug/CMakeFiles/3.13.1/CompilerIdC/a.exe"
  cannot be read.

Comment: Could you add your code to your post? (the content of the HelloWorld file, I guess)

Comment: The miles-long path names don't help anything, but maybe you can't avoid that.  It appears that a file called either `STRINGS` or `a.exe` is missing.  What happens next depends on which of those hypotheses is correct (if either), and where the file should be located etc.  I think that we'll need a lot more information, most of which is not really related to programming per se — it feels from here like a setup problem.  Have you been able to build any other programs?  Since this is "Hello World", I'm guessing not.  (I don't use CLion or CMake or Windows routinely, so I can't help much — sorry!)

Comment: #include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
   // printf() displays the string inside quotation
   printf("Hello, World!");
   return 0;
}

Comment: A very simple c program. I have a feeling that something might be messed up in the tool configurations. This is my first time using CLion so a mistake in setup could definitely be a possibility. If it helps, Im using it with mingw

Answer (score 0):

Did you setup the toolchain in CLion after you installed both MinGW and CLion?

`File > Settings > Build, Execution, Deployment > Toolchains`

CLion can normally autodetect the compilers that it knows about, however I believe that it still has to be told which compiler to look for at first.

Comment: I've added a screen shot of that section to the question. It says it has it.

Comment: From looking at my projects, that executable is in all of them, but only inside them; so I'm under the assumption that they're built when you attempt to compile.  Maybe if you rebuild your project and make sure that any malware protection software you have isn't preventing it from being created, that might help.